# Text shadow not showing on mobile mode

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello i have add some custom css to my post title but it does not show on mobile just on desktop

```
.td_module_wrap .entry-title {
font-family: GoodOTCond;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1;
    text-shadow: rgb(0 0 0) 0px 0px 0px, rgb(0 0 0) 0px 0px 10px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

[my weblink](https://web.thetekhne.com)

Comment: Which browser are you using on mobile? Does it support text-shadow at all?

Comment: Safari*  AND Chrome too.  yes they support it  they was there but know it is not working

Comment: Could you make a working snippet so we can try it and see the problem for ourselves without having to visit your site?